# Template argument deduction behavior with default arguments

Tags: c++, templates

EDITED (Original Question had only int A, int B):
Template argument deduction works as expected when the #arguments compared between specializations is the same, but fails when they are different (due to including default parameters included in one of the specialization).

For example : Why does template argument deduction fail in one case vs the other, can someone point to any resources / standard where this is explained ?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

template <int A, int B, int C, int D=1>
class Foo;

template <int A, int B, int C>
class Foo <A, B, C>
{
public:
    int a;

    Foo()
    {
        a = 0;
    }
};

template <int D>               // Fails compilation
class Foo <1, 1, 1, D>         // Fails compilation
//template <>                  // works, prints a = 1
//class Foo <1, 1, 1>          // works, prints a = 1
{
public:
    int a;

    Foo()
    {
        a = 1;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Foo <1, 1, 1, 1> f;
    std::cout << "a = "<< f.a << std::endl;
}
```

error: ambiguous template instantiation for ‘class Foo<1, 1, 1, 1>’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <int A>
class Foo <A> {/*..*/};
```

is with default argument:

```
template <int A>
class Foo <A, 1> {/*..*/};
```

With (valid):

```
template <int B>
class Foo <1, B> { /*..*/ };
```

You have ambiguity for `Foo<1, 1>`, both `Foo<A, 1>` and `Foo<1, B>` match, but neither is more specialized.

```
template <> class Foo <1> { /**/};
```

is

```
template <> class Foo <1, 1> { /**/};
```

and is more specialized than both previous specializations.

Comment: I guess in this simpler example, what you say makes perfect sense, so let me edit my question

Comment: So in the edited question  Foo<1, 1, 1, 1> matches better with Foo<1, 1, 1, D> as opposed to Foo<A, B, C, 1> - but still the compiler complains.

Comment: `Foo<1, 1, 1, D>` is not more **specialized** than `Foo<A, B, C, 1>`. Informally "T1 is more specialized than T2" means "T1 accepts fewer (a subset) types than T2".